# Get hierarchy of children using WorkItemLinks

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-sdk

I am trying to get all children of a given workitem id from tfs using tfs api and C#

Here is the scenario

Feature (Id: 1)

-> Product backlog item (Id: 2) ->Task (Id: 3)

-> Product backlog item (Id: 4)

Work item with Id: 1 has 2 children with Ids 2 & 4

Id: 2 has a child with Id: 3

When a work item id is passed I want to get all the children, complete tree so for the above scenario I when Id:1 is passed the method should return all the children Ids 2, 3, 4
Here is what I have so far, have difficulty doing the recursive call,,,can someone give me a hand

**Note:** I don’t want to use the wiql to return the hierarchy, I want to return all the children using WorkItemLinks

```
 public List<string> getWorkItemChildren(string Collection, string Project, int Id)
    {
        var teamCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("tfsConnection" + Collection));
        teamCollection.EnsureAuthenticated();
        WorkItemStore store = new WorkItemStore(teamCollection);
        Query query = new Query(store, "select * from issue where System.TeamProject = @project", new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "project", Project } });
        query.RunQuery();
        WorkItem workitem = store.GetWorkItem(Id);
        int parentLinkId = store.WorkItemLinkTypes.LinkTypeEnds["Parent"].Id;

        List<int> relatedWorkItemIds = new List<int>();
        List<string> relatedWorkItemType = new List<string>();
        if(workitem.Links.Count!=0)
        {
            foreach (WorkItemLink link in workitem.WorkItemLinks)
            {
                if (link.LinkTypeEnd.Id != parentLinkId)
                {
                    relatedWorkItemIds.Add(link.TargetId);

                }
            } 
        foreach (var linkType in relatedWorkItemIds)
        {
            WorkItem relatedWorkItem = store.GetWorkItem(linkType);
            relatedWorkItemType.Add(relatedWorkItem.Type.Name);
            foreach(WorkItemLink childlinks in relatedWorkItem.WorkItemLinks)
            {

            }
        }

        return relatedWorkItemType;

        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

Store.GetWorkItem(123);

Then iterate through the links and for each child link type do the same.

Then recurs...